# How to launch 'term' with my default shell without a prompt to select the shell?

Tags: term

I would like to launch `term` with my default shell, without being prompted every time for the path of the shell.

How can I bind a key to `term` without being prompted for the shell to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x t") (lambda ()
                                (interactive)
                                (term shell-file-name)))
```